# Is the additive inverse zero the same as the additive identity zero (vector spaces)?

Tags: vector-spaces

I have a textbook question that asks me to prove that there is only one zero-element of a vector space. There are many other questions that have asked this, but I was unsatisfied with the answers.

As far as I know, there are two axioms involved:

1. $\mathbf v+\mathbf 0=\mathbf v$
2. $\mathbf v+(-\mathbf v)=\mathbf0$

Is there a way to prove that the zero-vector in (1) is the same as the zero-vector in (2)? That is, I want to prove:

if $\mathbf v+\mathbf z=\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf v+(-\mathbf v)=\mathbf0$, then $\mathbf z=\mathbf0$

Answer (score 1):

It's a tautology that $v=v$.
Using the additive identity, we have $v=v+0$. Add the additive inverse $-v$ to both sides. Then $v+(-v)=0$.

Comment: It is a bit sloppy to "subtract" from both sides&mdash;it might be better to invoke additive cancelation.  However, this is otherwise elegantly phrased.  (+1)

Comment: Good point. We get old and start to take shortcuts :D

Comment: I believe all this shows is that it is possible that the two zeros are the same. Clearly it is possible. I don't think this proves that it must be the case that they are the same.